# Adding a group of EditText in Android on button click

Tags: android

Consider a simple scenario where user can add multiple address in a activity page. Address contains four ExitTexts for Name, Locality, city and pincode.

Requirement is that user can add/remove multiple addresses by clicking on add new button or delete button present at top of particular from.

How can I add or remove form (having multiple ExitTexts) dynamically on clicking add/remove buttons.

I have worked on form components having forms with predefined id's. But adding or removing  forms dynamically and getting the entered values is something which I am unable to achieve.  I am new to Android. Please help.

Comment: You can create a  layout for your view, inflate it in runtime and then add them to your current layout as you need. Look up: "android add view programmatically"

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a layout or in created layout and add EditText's in it.

Something like this,

```
//this code in button click

EditText edittext = new EditText(context);
edittext.setText("Name");
YOUR_LAYOUT.addView(edittext);

EditText edittext = new EditText(context);
edittext.setText("Locality");
YOUR_LAYOUT.addView(edittext);

EditText edittext = new EditText(context);
edittext.setText("City");
YOUR_LAYOUT.addView(edittext);

EditText edittext = new EditText(context);
edittext.setText("Pin Code");
YOUR_LAYOUT.addView(edittext);
```

or you can define seperate Edittext and add them in your layout.

Hope it Helps :)